# Dimensions of Smart Project UV Unwrap

Tags: scripting, uv

I'm UV unwrapping voxel-based models using the Smart Project. It can unwrap my models nicely (example below).

[image: UV Unwrap with Smart Project]

But I'm also trying to automate the process of exporting a properly sized image. For this I need to know how many edges are unwrapped in each dimension (For example, 32 edges by 32 edges in the posted image). Is there any way I can tell how many edges (or faces,tiles,vertices) the Smart Project unwraps in each direction without manually and visually counting them?

Or is there any other anyway I can set the image pixel dimensions to a certain size based on the number of faces?